# How to Run SQLAlchemy Query on Dask Distributed?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I am trying to run and parallelize this sqlalchemy query using a dask cluster I've set up, as I don't have enough memory to execute it from my local computer.

My code is as follows - I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed
client = Client(<IP Address>)

recent_dates = ['2020-04-24', '2020-04-23', 2020-04-22']

query = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '%s'"""
queries = [query.format(d) for d in recent_dates]

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
conn = create_engine(f'presto://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{catalog}/{schema}',
                           connect_args={'protocol': 'https',
                                         'requests_kwargs': {'verify': key}})

con = engine.connect()
df = dd.from_delayed([delayed(pd.read_sql_query)(q, conn) for q in queries])
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function `read_sql_table`, which is made for this very purpose. If you read the docstrings and/or the code, you will see that it is the query itself which is passed to the workers, which make their own engine instances locally. This is because the sqlalchemy instance has state that cannot be sent between workers, as you have found.

Note that `read_sql_table` also cares about partitioning your data, because this is Dask and the whole point is to deal with bigger-than-memory data. In your example, I guess the index/partitioning column is `date`, and you want to pass the "divisions" on which to split explicitly.